# Eclipse CDT Debugging and general workspace configuration

Tags: c++, eclipse, debugging, eclipse-cdt, bitcoin

I've been working on some code for some time now (bitcoin's source  code), the building system is GNU Autotools.
I'm having some problems debugging the code. I'm working with eclipse on OSX Mavericks, building the project works great but when i go to debugging prospective i'm having some problems:

- Many breakpoint cannot be installed
- Some breakpoints that can be installed cause a source not found error
- Cannot debug header files

A specific example is when i'm trying to debug step-by-step some of the unit tests, i can't seem to be able to step in functions.
I did: **./configure --with-miniupnpc --enable-upnp-default --with-qrencode --enable-debug** so to  include debugging flags.

**Anyone care to share how he setup his workspace or how to resolve those problems ?**

ANYONE ???

Comment: Try to turn off compiler optimizations.

Comment: Optimization is off
CXXFLAGS = -g3 -O0 -DDEBUG -Wall -Wextra -Wformat -Wformat-security -Wno-unused-parameter  -Wstack-protector -fstack-protector-all -fPIE